# inversify: not injectable contrustor arguments

Tags: inversifyjs

I have a Game class and a Multiplayer class which handle all network players stuff for defined game:

```
export interface Multiplayer{
    game: Game
    start()
}
export class WebSocketMultiplayer implements Multiplayer{
    constructor(public game: Game){}
    start(){}
}
```

inversify configuration:

```
container.bind<Game>('Game').to(BasicGame)
container.bind<Multiplayer>('Multiplayer').to(WebSocketMultiplayer)
```

now I want to create, configure and run game and after that - run multiplayer.

```
const game = kernel.get<Game>('Game')
game.run()
const multiplayer = kernel.get<Multiplayer>('Multiplayer')
multiplayer.start()
```

but how should I pass game instance into `Multiplayer` constructor?
If I will use `@inject` in `WebSocketMultiplayer` constructor than it will create another game instance.

Temporary solution I'm using for now is to pass game instance in multiplayer start function

```
start(game: Game){
        this.game = game
}
```

but how it suppose to be done with Inversify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You ca try a few things.

The first options is to use the `inSingletonScope` method:

```
container.bind<Game>('Game').to(BasicGame).inSingletonScope();
```

You can learn more about scope [here](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/blob/master/wiki/scope.md).

The second option is to use a factory:

```
container.bind<Game>('Game').to(BasicGame);
container.bind<Multiplayer>('Multiplayer').to(WebSocketMultiplayer);

container.bind<() => Game>("GameFactory").toFactory<Game>((context: interfaces.Context) => {
    const game = context.container.get<Game>("Game");
    game.run();
    return () => game;
});

class WebSocketMultiplayer implements Multiplayer{
    public game: Game;
    constructor(@inject("GameFactory") gameFactory: () => Game){
        this.game = gameFactory();
    }
    start(){}
}
```

If `game.run()` is asynchronous then you will need an asynchronous factory (AKA [provider](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/blob/master/wiki/provider_injection.md)).

Comment: are there any chances to use `toProvider` with custom promise library or it requrie native promises?